# Region name for an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code

Tags: php, internationalization, locale, icu, intl

In a database we have [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements), e.g. GB for United Kingdom and AR for Argentina. Today we keep a database table with one column for these country codes and one for corresponding English country names.

We work in PHP (5.4.x) which has the [intl extenion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) (wrapper for ICU library) so I thought I'd like to fetch the country names from this source which makes the application more maintainable and easier to internationalize as I easily can fetch country names in German, French or whatever we want in the future.

`Locale::getDisplayRegion ( string $locale [, string $in_locale ] )` provides a region name from a locale.
E.g.

```
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en-US', 'de') . PHP_EOL;
Vereinigte Staaten
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en-US', 'en') . PHP_EOL;
United States
```

The problem is that I do not have the language code, only the country code, so I'm not sure how to build up a proper locale.

It seems like I can get the region names by just prefixing with 'en_' for English, e.g

```
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en-CH', 'en') . PHP_EOL;
Switzerland
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en-CN', 'en') . PHP_EOL;
China
php > echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('en-AR', 'en') . PHP_EOL;
Argentina
```

However, this feels more like a hack and I'm not sure I really can rely on that?

I was thinking if I could somehow compose a locale using the country code (region / territory depending on terminology) and any of the valid languages for the country, but it appears it doesn't work as far as I've found at least:

```
php > echo Locale::composeLocale( array('region' => 'CN') ) . PHP_EOL;

php >
```

Any recommendations on how to go about this?
I do not want to maintain my own database of country names or simply use an external PHP library for it when there's a built-in extension which seem to be a good source (ICU) already.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think since a Locale object is made up of language and country, you'll find that the "en" trick often works but might break down in the cases such as en_US (English, United States) vs en_GB (English, United Kingdom). Without knowing the language component, you can't know the exact locale.

Comment: Why would it break down in cases such as en_US / en_GB specifically? I'm always just looking for the country name so it doesn't really matter what language data the intl extension could return, all I need to be sure about is whether it's safe to pass a locale containing a language together with a country code where it doesn't really exist. I'm just afraid it at some point would throw an error back at me or give no data due to invalid Locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `und` (unknown language).  So `'und_' . 'AR'` etc.